# dynamic cast throws pointer is not std::__non_rtti_object

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, dynamic-cast

I'm having problem with dynamic_cast. i just compiled my project and tested every thing in debug mode and then i tried compiling it in release mode, i have copied every configuration from debug mode exept optimization parameter which is now /o2, (while debuging i set it as /od) the project compiled but when it starts loading my resources i got exception in the piece of code here :

```
for(int j = 1; j < i->second->getParametersNumber();j++)
{
    CCTMXTiledMap* temp = CCTMXTiledMap::tiledMapWithTMXFile(i->second->As<string>(j).c_str());
    CCTMXLayer* ret = NULL;
    for(NSMutableArray<CCNode*>::NSMutableArrayIterator l=temp->getChildren()->begin();!ret && l!=temp->getChildren()->end();l++)
        ret = dynamic_cast<CCTMXLayer*> (*l);
    t1.first = ret;
    templates[i->first].second.push_back(t1);
    templates[i->first].second.back().first->retain();
}
```

nothing in code changed and when I check in debugger every variable in classes is what it should be but dynamic cast is throwing  std::__non_rtti_object. what am i doing it wrong? and i'm using cocos2d-x ,I didn't have enough reputation to add that tag!

Comment: Are you sure you have RTTI enabled in your release config? I.e. are you sure you really copied *everything* from the debug config?

Comment: yes,and yes. RTTI is enabled and every thing is copied from debug configuration

Comment: In that case is must be a bad pointer. There are millions of reasons bad code might work in debug build and fail in release build.

Comment: again i tested but *l is just what it should be all it's parameters are they should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case after many code changes I found out there has to be some bugs which show themselves when code is optimized (still don't know if it's compiler's mis optimization or my code has some problems but it's probably mine). and the main reason for that problem was with `*l` being NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Does `CCNode` have any virtual functions? Are all elements of temp->getChildren()->begin() really `CCNode`s? Does `temp->getChildren()` return a reference? The latter is especially insidious: you call both `temp->getChildren()->begin()` and `temp->getChildren()->end()`. If `getChildren()` returns a copy, you're taking the `begin` of one copy and the `end` of another copy.

Comment: it does have many virtual functions and i'm saying it word while in debug configuration if it didin't debug configuration would also made errors!