# reinterpret_cast acting as dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My code is like this:

```
void some_func(void *source)
{
    ...
    double *casted = reinterpret_cast<double *>(source);
    ...
}
```

This causes `std::__non_rtti_object` exception. Acording to stack trace, it is raised from `__RTDynamicCast`, which is (as far as i know) MSVC implementation of dynamic_cast.

This exception should occur with dynamic_cast, as the pointer comes from external library (probably compiled without /GR) and points to struct with several doubles. But I would not expect this with reinterpret_cast. Shouldn't it just change the type of the pointer, without any checks at all?

Notes:

- my compiler is msvc120 (MS Visual Studio 2013)
- project is compiled with /GR (enable run-time type information)
- pointer "source" comes from external library (probably compiled without /GR)
- I also tried static_cast with the same result

Comment: Seems odd, RTTI should not affect a `reinterpret_cast`. What happens with an old-style C cast (e.g. `(double*)source`)?

Comment: Even though [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582874/dynamic-cast-throws-pointer-is-not-std-non-rtti-object) deals with that exception being thrown from a `dynamic_cast`, the OP's answer says that the problem was that the pointer was `nullptr`. Are you sure `source != nullptr`?

Comment: I don't believe you've shown us enough of the code to determine the problem. This looks perfectly valid to me, even if you're casting a null pointer.

Comment: Same result, with (double *)source.

Comment: Is there a chance of malicious macro defining `reinterpret_cast` (and `static_cast`) as `dynamic_cast` being present somewhere? Oh, I see... `(double *)source` doesn't work either.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is mostly implementation defined, so that is one expected result.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: It is not *that* implementation defined. The only freedom the implementation has here is the actual value of the result. It has no freedom to generate an RTTI-related failure.

Comment: Can you stop at the line in debugger, do `Alt+8` and copy-paste the assembly it generated for the cast?

Comment: Ah, i tried to rebuild whole project with all additional libraries and the problem disappeared. Seems strange, because I never had a code using dynamic_cast, so don't know what caused this. Also I already tried to rebuild that project only (without other dlls) before. Anyway, thanks for all help.

Comment: @Praetorian: Why would a `nullptr` cause a failure in this cast?

Comment: @AndreyT I don't think it should, but given that a `reinterpret_cast` is throwing some RTTI related exception, I thought it might be worth a shot, even though it's a stretch.

Comment: Just noting that `static_cast<double *>(source)` is equivalent (and ,arguably, better style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-reproducible.

> Ah, i tried to rebuild whole project with all additional libraries and
>   the problem disappeared. Seems strange, because I never had a code
>   using dynamic_cast, so don't know what caused this. Also I already
>   tried to rebuild that project only (without other dlls) before.
>   Anyway, thanks for all help.
>   -- [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503708/reinterpret-cast-acting-as-dynamic-cast#comment30649889_20503708)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as that you need to recheck dll's order of build in your makefile (if you use such). I guess that the source from the external library you mentioned, comes from external library that is "higher" in the build tree than the library which your code resides. Try to see if your makefile properly works (maybe misses some triggers).